# When I use a CuRL request in Laravel it returns false

Tags: php, laravel, api, rest, curl

I have a method that sends an SMS message but instead returns false. The code is used in Postman, and it works. I am using Laravel 5.8.

```
public function sendSMS()
{
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array(URL_API, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => '{
                "number" : PHONE_NUMBER,
                "message" : "Tu código de seguridad es: 289686",
                "type" : 1
            }',
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            'api-key: API_KEY',
            'Authorization: Bearer TOKEN_API',
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        ),
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    echo $response;
}
```

**Response in Laravel**

```
 [false]
 0: false
```

**Response in Postman**

```
{
    "success": true,
    "message": "Enviado",
    "number": "11111111111",
    "menssageId": 122585244
}
```

I verified that CURL is enabled on my localhost.

```
cURL support      : enabled
cURL Information  : 7.70.0
```

Comment: try:   `if (!$response) { print curl_error($curl); }`   after `curl_exec`  or better use Guzzle

Comment: Is this the code generated from postman?

Comment: @NickMaroulis yes, I copied the code from postman

Comment: @num8er I tried, but not working.

Comment: @FcoCandelario maybe sms server is not allowing ip of server? it should be checked from serverside using curl, telnet manually - cause You say curl is installed but You don't get error? nonesense.

Comment: put this params:     `CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true,   CURLOPT_STDERR => fopen('./curl.log', 'w+')` and do request, after check that log file for information.

Answer (score 0):

I thank you all for your time, the solution was added two parameters in the curl query.

```
public static function sendSMS($number,$message){
        
        $token = json_decode(self::loginCELLVOZ(),true);

        $url        = env('URL_BASE') . 'sms/single';
        $account    = env('ACCOUNT');
        $password   = env('PASSWORD');
        $api_key    = env('API_KEY');

        $phone = '551'.$number;
        
        
        $curl = curl_init();

        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => $url,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false, //add line 
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false, //add line
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'{
                "number" : "'.$phone.'",
                "message" : "'.$message.'",
                "type" : 1
            }',
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                'api-key: '.$api_key.'',
                'Authorization: Bearer '.$token['token'].'',
                'Content-Type: application/json'
            ),
        ));

        $response = curl_exec($curl);

        curl_close($curl);

        return $response;
}
```

NOTE:

Only is necesary this lines in localhost, not recomendly use in the server production.